# Unity aircraft physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, air, physics

I want to make a simple aircraft controller, what looks like little realistic in unity. I watch some video from airplane physics. and make a simple script in unity, but if I start, my plane cant move or if I change drag to zero, it cant lift. I tried to use real data and get it from wiki(F22 Raptor). To my game object, I gave the rigidbody component mass = 19670 kg. 
Engine thrust = 2 * 116000.0f Newton.

```
    private void calculateEnginePower()
    {
        EnginePower = engineThrust * ThrottleInput;
    }

    private void calculateForces()
    {
        angleOfAttack = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, rb.velocity);
        angleOfAttack = Mathf.Clamp(angleOfAttack, 0, 90);

        coefficient = Mathf.Pow(1225.04f * rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) - 1; //M^2-2 where: M is mach.         

        if (coefficient > 0.0f)
            coefficientLift = (4 * angleOfAttack) / Mathf.Sqrt(coefficient);
        lift = 1.2754f * 0.5f * Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) * coefficientLift * 78.04f; // densy1.2754 kg/m3, speed m/s , (F22)Wing area: 840 ft² (78.04 m²)

        coefficientDrag = 0.021f;
        rb.drag = coefficientDrag * 0.5f * Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude,2) * 1.2754f * 78.04f;

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * lift);
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * EnginePower);
    }
```

used these formulas:

for Lift force:
[Lift formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WARcq.png)
for Lift coefficient:
[Cl formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Akw.png)
for Drag:
[Drag formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54IHk.png)
and for Drag coefficient: I used data from wiki too (0.021f).

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see the values of `lift` and `EnginePower`? Where are you calling `calculateForces`?

Comment: roll,pitch... inputs from keyboard and mouse, EnginePower is a simple property and i call the Move function in a controller inside void Update.
public void Move(float roll, float pitch, float yaw, float throttle)
        {
            // transfer input parameters into properties.s
            RollInput = roll;
            PitchInput = pitch;
            YawInput = yaw;
            ThrottleInput = throttle;
            AirBrakes = false;

            calculateEnginePower();
            calculateForces();
            calculateRotation();
        }

Comment: you can call it too in Move function for debugging.       

 private void debugThings()
        {
            Debug.Log("Aoa: " + angleOfAttack);
            Debug.Log("cL: " + coefficientLift);
            Debug.Log("Lift: " + lift);
            Debug.Log("cD: " + coefficientDrag);
            Debug.Log("Drag: " + drag);
            Debug.Log("Mass: " + rb.mass);
            Debug.Log("Speed: " + rb.velocity.magnitude);


            Debug.DrawLine(rb.position, rb.velocity * 300, Color.red);
        }

Comment: What are typical values for `lift` at full thrust? How do they compare to the weight of the plane? (`g` might not be 9.81 in Unity units, but I'm unsure about that - best way is to find out with an experiment). According to [this forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/drag-factor-what-is-it.85504/) the `drag` property seems to have rather arbitrary units (and it is unclear what it *exactly* represents)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So there are a number of issues with your code. I've outlined them below;

**Calculate Forces**

---

> **Issue:** `angleOfAttack = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, rb.velocity);`

- `Vector3.forward` and `rb.velocity` are both in **world-space**. `AoA` is the angle between the **local** chord-line of your wing and the aircraft's `velocity`.
- `Vector3.Angle` will return an **unsigned** angle. `AoA` must work in both **positive** and **negative** directions otherwise negative pitch and inverted flight would not be possible.

[image]

> **Solution:**
>   *Move `rb.velocity` to local-space and solve for `AoA` with trigonometry.*

```
// *flip sign(s) if necessary*
var localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(rb.velocity);
var angleOfAttack = Mathf.Atan2(-localVelocity.y, localVelocity.z);
```

---

> **Issue:** 
>   `coefficient = Mathf.Pow(1225.04f * rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) - 1;`

- `4α/sqrt(M^2−1)` is a supersonic wave coefficient for **M > 1**. At zero velocity this equation will reduce to `sqrt(-1)` which is an imaginary number that will produce `NaN`. Mach is expressed as `M=V/C` where `V=velocity` and `C=the speed of sound`. Your `1225.04f` constant must be `C` in units of km/h and not **m/s** as required. You're also multiplying and not **dividing** as given in the equation.

> **Solution:** 
>   *Simplify your equations with Lifting Line Theory.*

```
var aspectRatio = (wingSpan * wingSpan) / wingArea; 
var inducedLift = angleOfAttack * (aspectRatio / (aspectRatio + 2f)) * 2f * Mathf.PI;
var inducedDrag = (inducedLift * inducedLift) / (aspectRatio * Mathf.PI);
```

[image]

*Source:* [*Aerospaceweb.org*](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/aerodynamics/q0184.shtml)

---

> **Issue:** 
>   `rb.drag = coefficientDrag * 0.5f * Pow(rb.velocity.mag,2) * 1.2754f * 78.04f;`

- `rb.drag` is not required since we're calculating and applying drag manually.

> **Solution:**
>   *Set the `rb.drag` property to the smallest possible value.*

```
rb.drag = Mathf.Epsilon; // set in Awake
```

---

> **Issue:**
>   `rb.AddForce(transform.up * lift);`

- `transform.up` is not correct for `lift`. Lift acts **perpendicular** to `velocity` while `drag` acts **parallel**.

[image]

> **Solution:** 
>   *Compute the `lift` direction by crossing the normalized `velocity` vector with the aircraft's lateral direction and apply `drag` opposite to `velocity`.*

```
// *flip sign(s) if necessary*
var dragDirection = -rb.velocity.normalized;
var liftDirection = Vector3.Cross(dragDirection, transform.right);
rb.AddForce(liftDirection * lift + dragDirection * drag);
```

---

Your lift equation looks OK, so putting it all together would look something like this; (*Untested*)

```
public float wingSpan = 13.56f;
public float wingArea = 78.04f;

private float aspectRatio;

private void Awake ()
{
    rb.drag = Mathf.Epsilon;
    aspectRatio = (wingSpan * wingSpan) / wingArea;
}

private void calculateForces ()
{
    // *flip sign(s) if necessary*
    var localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(rb.velocity);
    var angleOfAttack = Mathf.Atan2(-localVelocity.y, localVelocity.z);

    // α * 2 * PI * (AR / AR + 2)
    var inducedLift = angleOfAttack * (aspectRatio / (aspectRatio + 2f)) * 2f * Mathf.PI;

    // CL ^ 2 / (AR * PI)
    var inducedDrag = (inducedLift * inducedLift) / (aspectRatio * Mathf.PI);

    // V ^ 2 * R * 0.5 * A
    var pressure = rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude * 1.2754f * 0.5f * wingArea;

    var lift = inducedLift * pressure;
    var drag = (0.021f + inducedDrag) * pressure;

    // *flip sign(s) if necessary*
    var dragDirection = rb.velocity.normalized;
    var liftDirection = Vector3.Cross(dragDirection, transform.right);

    // Lift + Drag = Total Force
    rb.AddForce(liftDirection * lift - dragDirection * drag);
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * EnginePower);
}
```